# flutter cloud firestore delete doc

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

i have created checkbox list which when its true it should upload my document on firestore and i have no problem with that... but when i try to uncheckbox it won't delete what i have uploaded... here is why:
i have 2 lists...first one is `PlanExerciseslist[index]` which displays all the data in the list by its index while using listView.Separated / and the other list is `List<String> planDayExID =[];` which it contains all documents id on firestore that i have uploaded.

my real problem is this : for example if i uploaded a document which its index is 4 by clicking on checkbox...my id list will get this document as index 0 so if i unchecked my checkbox it won't be deleted

here is my code:

```
class BackPlanScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  PlanQsModel model;
  int dayNum;
  int weekNum;
  BackPlanScreen(this.model,this.dayNum,this.weekNum);

  @override
  State<BackPlanScreen> createState() => _BackPlanScreenState();
}

class _BackPlanScreenState extends State<BackPlanScreen> {
  late List<bool> isChecked;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    isChecked = List<bool>.filled(LifeStyleCubit.get(context).PlanExerciseslist.length, false);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return BlocConsumer<LifeStyleCubit,LifeStates>(
      listener: (context,state)
      {},
      builder: (context,state)
      {
        var cubit = LifeStyleCubit.get(context);
        cubit.getPlanBackEx1(widget.model.level);
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Text('Exercise'),
          ),
          body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20.0),
            child: ListView.separated(
                scrollDirection: Axis.vertical,
                itemBuilder:(context,index) => BackWidget(cubit.PlanExerciseslist[index],context,index),
                separatorBuilder: (context,index) => SizedBox(height: 35,),
                itemCount: cubit.PlanExerciseslist.length
            ),
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }

  Widget BackWidget (PlanExercisesModel model,context,index) => GestureDetector(
    onTap: () => Navigator.push(context,
        MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context)=>BackPlanGifScreen(model))),
    child: Builder(
      builder: (context) {
        return Container(
          height: 100,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Checkbox(
                    value: isChecked[index],
                    activeColor: Colors.orangeAccent,
                    onChanged: (newBool){
                      setState(() {
                        isChecked[index] = newBool!;
                        if (isChecked[index] == true)
                        {
                          LifeStyleCubit.get(context).createPlanExercisesDay(
                            name: model.name,
                            difficulty: model.difficulty,
                            bodyPart: model.bodyPart,
                            equipment: model.equipment,
                            gifURL: model.gifURL,
                            target: model.target,
                            weekNum:widget.weekNum+1,
                            dayNum: widget.dayNum+1,
                            id: widget.model.description,
                          );
                        }
                        if(isChecked[index] == false){
                          LifeStyleCubit.get(context).deletePlanExercisesDay(
                              weekNum: widget.weekNum+1,
                              dayNum: widget.dayNum+1,
                              id: widget.model.description,
                              exID: LifeStyleCubit.get(context).planDayExID[index]
                          );
                        }
                      });
                    }
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    ),
  );
}

void deletePlanExercisesDay({
    required int weekNum,
    required int dayNum,
    required String id,
    required String exID,
})
  {
    FirebaseFirestore.instance
        .collection('users').doc(uId).collection('plans').doc('addPlan')
        .collection('addPlan').doc(id).collection('week $weekNum')
        .doc('week $weekNum').collection('day $dayNum').doc(exID)
        .delete()
        .then((value){
      emit(deletePlanExercisesSuccessState());
    }).catchError((error)
    {
      emit(deletePlanExercisesErrorState(error.toString()));
    });
  }
```

how to implement that?

Comment: You could introduce `Map<String, int>` to keep track of the mapping between document IDs and their index in the `planDayExID` list. So Update(add or remove from) this Map whenever you add or remove the document using those if checks

Comment: Hi does that comment solve your issue ? if so I will post an answer so other community members will also get the answer for this question.

Comment: to be honest i used another way to implement what i needed...i made a loop to get all documents and when i uncheckbox it will search for all documents and it will delete the document that has one of its attribute "name" = the same "name" of the PlanExerciseslist[index]

Comment: Glad to see you solved it, also Take a look at [this snippet](https://codefile.io/f/ioYooOgn3AfQgZe20Rk7) here I have used List to track the mapping between document IDs and their index in the `planDayExID` list.